# How to Add momemt to Angular-datatable 6.0

Tags: angular6, angular-datatables

I am using angular-datatables@6.0.0(https://github.com/l-lin/angular-datatables) with angular 6.

I want to add moment plugin to datatables. i couldn't find any documentation for this.

Is there any function like render in datatable.net for columns in angular-datatables@6.0.0

Answer (score 0):

You can add a moment model in Angular 5.0 and newer. with help of the following link.

[ngx-moment](https://github.com/urish/ngx-moment)

Comment: I want to add the moment to the Datatable. not to angular